# MacOS Big Sur edit the image in this folder: System/Library/Desktop Pictures/Big Sur Graphic.heic

Tags: python, macos, system

need to help a client change this image he has cataracts and can't see well. plz help. If i knew how to mount and edit the system drive that would do it